# Add Image to DevExtreme React Grid Bootstrap4 Column

Tags: reactjs, grid

I'm using react to show a grid with data from my database.
The data is showing properly, but its all text data.
I would like to show an icon at the first column.
This is what I have right now:

```
<Grid
  rows={products}
  columns={[
    { name: "icon", title: "Icon" },
    { name: "name", title: "Name" },
    { name: "desc", title: "Desc" },
    { name: "price", title: "Price" },
   ]
}></grid>
```

My `{products}` contains all data.
When I run this the `Icon` column contains image344.png and not an actual image.
What do I need to do to make the `Icon` column show an image instead of text?
I also tried to set the icon value to this `<img src='image344.png'>` but it still shows text.
Please help!

Comment: Which component are you using ? I mean what is <Grid/>

Comment: Grid is a component of dx-react-grid-bootstrap4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grid if give value as text it will show the actual text only. so create the actual html element for the icon column, then it will show the image icon.

Sample data added below to render the image in the Grid view.

```
var products= [{icon:'image344.png',name:'test',desc:'test',price:'123'}];
 products = products.map(function(data){
    data.icon = <img src={data.icon}/>;
    return data;
 });

<Grid
  rows={products}
  columns={[
    { name: "icon", title: "Icon" },
    { name: "name", title: "Name" },
    { name: "desc", title: "Desc" },
    { name: "price", title: "Price" },
   ]
}></grid>
```

Comment: What If I tell ya I can't modify the data inside the products array, I get the array from an API, so I get the data and use it, is it stil possible to remove the quotes then?

Comment: Yes. You can still traverse through the array using javascript map function and modify the data as needed or please share the mock response data I will do it and update the answer.

Comment: `var products= [{icon: 'image344.png',name:'test',desc:'test',price:'123'}]` this is the response data, how can I update icon data?

Comment: @user10759494 I have dited the answer. Please check now.

Comment: It gives me the error: `Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: You are using any typescript? If you are typescript, then change the icon type to accept both string or element type.